# How to build java 9 dependencies from maven dependencies

Tags: java, maven, java-9, modularity, module-info

Java9 has introduced a strong modularity similar to OSGI and Maven Dependecies.

**Is there a maven plugin able to build the java 9 dependencies inspecting maven dependencies?**

For example, **from**

```
<groupId>com.mycompany.app</groupId>
<artifactId>my-module</artifactId>
....
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
    <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
    <version>23.3-jre</version>
</dependency>
```

**to**

```
module my-module{
    requires com.google.guava;
    exports com.mycompany.app; 
}
```

I have read this article, but it is not so useful -
 [How to express dependency in maven on java ee features for transition to Java 9?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46084751/how-to-express-dependency-in-maven-on-java-ee-features-for-transition-to-java-9)

Comment: Robert Scholte has a write-up on this topic here: https://www.sitepoint.com/maven-cannot-generate-module-declaration/

Comment: By the way, `requires com.google.guava` should be `requires com.google.common` instead.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can Maven generate the module declaration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43201997/can-maven-generate-the-module-declaration)

Answer (score 7):

To answer the question precisely, the names of modules in the `module-info` as referenced in question like `com.google.guava`per say are called the *automatic* module name. Generally, if you already have a jar with Java 8 for your app, let's say `yourApp.jar` with the above maven configuration. You can make use of the [`jdeps` tool](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/tools/jdeps.htm#JSWOR690) as:-

```
jdeps --generate-module-info <output-dir> /path/to/yourApp.jar
```

which would generate the `module-info.java` for your jar that you can further make use of while migrating the same project to Java 9.

The current corresponding plugin under the name [`maven-jdeps-plugin`](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-jdeps-plugin/) does not seem to be supporting this task. Though its still [Work in Progress](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/Java+9+-+Jigsaw) and this might pitch in, *if seen effective by the owners to be introduced in the Maven workflow.*

***Edit*** **::** Just in case you find the task useful the feature can be requested at [MJDEPS tracker.](https://issues.apache.org/jira/projects/MJDEPS)

Answer (score 4):

There is a plugin in this github repo https://github.com/moditect/moditect allowing to do that.

In your example, put the following in the maven build:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.moditect</groupId>
  <artifactId>moditect-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.0.Alpha2</version>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>add-module-infos</id>
      <phase>package</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>add-module-info</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
        <module>
          <moduleInfo>
            <name>com.mycompany.app.my.module</name>
          </moduleInfo>
        </module>
      </configuration>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

and under `target/moditect` you may find the generated `module-info.java`

Comment: the link is fine. But you can post some details that make your answer a better one

Comment: improved the answer with some details