# How to create a runnable Jar file using Jigsaw modules

Tags: java, module, java-9, runnable-jar

I try to learn about the modules introduced in java 9.
I try to create a runnable Jar. I have the main module, which I want to run and one dependendency module, helloWorldModule.

Module: mainModule
main/Main.java

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Greeter greeter = new Greeter();
        greeter.sayHello();
    }
}


module mainModule {
    requires helloWorldModule;
}
```

Module: helloWorldModule
helloWorld/Greeter.java

```
public class Greeter {
    
    public void sayHello(){
        System.out.println("Hello there!");
    }
}

module helloWorldModule {
    exports helloWorld;
}
```

I've exported the modules to two jars.
I can run it like that without any problems.

```
   java --module-path lib --module mainModule/main.Main
```

But I have to have both modules inside my custom lib folder to make that work.
On my research about that, I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47875351/multiple-java-9-modules-from-a-single-maven-module), that one Module is always compiled into one jar. This  means, that I can not put my helloWorldModule inside the main module jar file, but as the mainModule requires that helloWorldModule, I can't create a runnable JAR file.

What is the correct way to package my program into a runnable file now?

Comment: Create the module jar with `jar`’s `e` option to specify the main class. Then, you only need `--module mainModule` instead of `--module mainModule/main.Main` (or even use `-m mainModule`). Then, you can use `jlink`, to create a Java runtime containing (only the required) JDK modules and your modules. The resulting environment does already have an implied module path, so you can run the application with `java -m mainModule` when using the launcher of that environment.